# handling newline character in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have created a table in hive as

```
Create table(id int, Description String)
```

My data looks something as follows :

```
 
1|This will return corrupt data since there is a ',' in the first string.
     some text
     Change the data  
2|There is prob in reading data 
    sometext
```

After the data is loaded into hive since the default line terminator is \n, the description column cannot be read by hive, Hence it displays a NULL value. Can anyone suggest how to handle newline before loading into hive.

Comment: has anyone come across this kind of situation where particular value in field is multiline?

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is old, but you have a couple of options.  You can't control this with `FIELDS TERMINATED BY`, because that only controls what terminates the fields, not the records.  Records in Hive are hard-coded to be terminated by the newline character (even though there is a `LINES TERMINATED BY` clause, it is not implemented).

1. Write a custom `InputFormat` that uses a `RecordReader` that
   understands non-newline delimited records.  Look at the code for
   `LineReader`/`LineRecordReader` and `TextInputFormat`.
2. Use a format
   other than text/ASCII, like Parquet.  I would recommend this
   regardless, as text is probably the worst format you can store data
   in anyway.

Answer (score 1):

try adding the below property in hive-site.xml or you can just try for temporary hive session level.

hive.query.result.fileformat=SequenceFile

Answer (score -3):

By default hive takes in NEWLINE ('\N') as delimiter .
You can change the delimiter using:

```
    ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ",";
```

Comment: i'm aware of this option. field separation is not a issue. the second field (string) in my case is multiline field(field value for particular record is spread over multiple lines)

Comment: Is it like , when u select * the table u get 1 text or 1 NULL

Comment: First row loads correctly but when it encounters new line( in the second field value) it puts null values

Comment: ya same !! so have you tried changing the delimiter to a non-newline character?