# how to create hive table with line separator other than \n

Tags: hive, line

My data field contains newline characters in it. We need to include these newline character in the data. Is it possible to create a hive table with embedded newlines?

Comment: Did [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26339564/handling-newline-character-in-hive) help any?

Answer (score 0):

Add `LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'` to your create command and replace \n with a char you like.

But really this was the first result to find at google...