# hive "\n" value in records

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-s3, hive

I am processing a large 120 GB file using hive. Data is first loaded from sql server table to aws s3 as csv file (tab separated) and then hive external table is created on top of this file. I have encountered a problem while querying data from hive external table. I noticed that csv contains \n in many columns fields (which was actually “null” in sql server). Now when I create hive table the \n that appears in any record takes hive to new record and generate NULL for rest of the columns in that record. I tried lines terminated by "001" but no success. I get error that hive only supports only "lines terminated by \n". My question is if hive supports only \n as line separator how would you handle columns that contains \n values?
Any suggestions?

This is how I am creating my external table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS IMPT_OMNITURE__Browser;

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IMPT_OMNITURE__Browser ( 
     ID int, Region string, Description string
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LOCATION 's3://abm-dw/data-import/omniture/Browser/';
```

Comment: How do you create the external table ? You should always post the relevant piece of code along with your question, otherwise we can't really help you.

Comment: I added the query for creating external table. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30945253/6096232)

Answer (score 0):

You could alter the table with the below command or add the property in the create statement in the TBL properties ;

```
ALTER TABLE table set SERDEPROPERTIES ('serialization.null.format' = "");
```

This would make the data in the file as NULL.

Comment: I tried below serde properties, but it did not help,  the behavior is same

Comment: row format serde 'com.bizo.hive.serde.csv.CSVSerde'
with serdeproperties
("separatorChar" = "\t",
"serialization.null.format" = " ")