# Hive new line character issue when creating table over text file format

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, newline

I have text file in hdfs location and I want to create hive table on top of that. The file contains new line character in between the end of line (EOL). But when i am creating hive table delimited by \n the new line character present in between the EOL is considered as new row and the resulting hive table is containing more number of rows than required. How I can i tell hive to ignore the new line character present before the EOL. 
Note : In my case i can't edit the hdfs file.

Comment: What do you mean by EOL? What charecter is used as "end of line" character in your text files?

Comment: You have to write a Job to escape the in-between '\n' character, and then put this file in HDFS and create table and all..., there is no way you can tell Hive to do that.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [handling newline character in hive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26339564/6096232)

Answer (score 0):

you have windows carriage return in your file  "\r\n"

In that case use Table **LINES TERMINATED BY  '\r\n'**

Comment: No windows carriage return is not present. Actually that hdfs file is generated as a sqoop result.

Comment: can you attache sample